# Easiest Way to Find The Inverse Matrix by using Row Canonical Form.

Tags: matrices

I want to find the Inverse of a Matrix in Row Canonical Form . I have tried several ways to do that but failed. Is there any easy way to find the Inverse of Matrix in row canonical form? Let A be the following 3x3 Matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 4 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 & 3 \\
   2 & 5 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
How can we find it's inverse using row canonical form?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is to perform Gauss-Jordan elimination on the matrix (that is, to convert it to the Row Canonical Form):
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
3&4&-1&1&0&0\\
1&0&3&0&1&0\\
2&5&-4&0&0&1
\end{array}\right]$$
If $A$ is invertible, the left hand side will be the identity matrix while the right hand side gives you $A^{-1}$.